# ERROR "Email already exists" Omniauth-facebook & Devise when multiple emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using omniauth-facebook and devise for authentication in my rails 4 app. I would like for a user, with multiple emails, that already has authenticated through devise, also be able to add facebook auth later if they choose.

**Device settings:**

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,
    :lockable, :timeoutable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook]
```

**user.rb**

```
def self.from_omniauth auth
    email = Email
      .includes(:user)
      .where(email: auth.info.email)
      .first_or_initialize

    ui = Identity
      .where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid)
      .first_or_initialize

    if ui.persisted?
      # Existing user, Existing social identity
      if ! email.persisted?
        # Email changed on third party site
        email.user = ui.user
        email.save!
        ui.email = email
      elsif email.user == ui.user
        ui.user
      else
        raise Exceptions::EmailConflict.new
      end
    elsif email.persisted?
      # Existing User, new identity
      ui.user = email.user
      ui.save!
      ui.user
    else
      # New user new identity
      email.save!
      user = User.new(
        password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
        default_email: email
      )
      user.save!
      ui.user = user
      ui.email = email
      ui.save!
    end

    ui.user
  end
private

  def save_default_email
    if default_email.user.blank?
      default_email.user = self
    elsif default_email.user != self
      raise Exceptions::EmailConflict
    end
    default_email.save!
  end
```

**Logs:**

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Email has already been taken):
app/models/user.rb:98:in `save_default_email' 
app/models/user.rb:82:in `from_omniauth'
```